# How to convert SQL subquery into Join Clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Good day everyone,

I have been attempting to convert the following SQL statement into a join clause, however I have been unable to figure out how to do it and was wondering if I could get some help.

Here is the statement:

```
SELECT OrderID FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate = (SELECT orderDate FROM Orders WHERE OrderID = 10280);
```

I am essentially trying to get all orderIDs that were placed on the same date as the Order with OrderID 10280.

Thanks,

Comment: Your requirement isn't clear. Orders are placed with orderId, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT o.OrderId 
FROM Orders o
JOIN Orders ord 
ON o.OrderDate = ord.OrderDate 
WHERE ord.OrderID = 10280;
```

You can have a better understanding from here: [https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-self-join/#:~:text=A%20self%20join%20allows%20you,join%20or%20left%20join%20clause](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-self-join/#:%7E:text=A%20self%20join%20allows%20you,join%20or%20left%20join%20clause).